# Como buscar por arquivos antigos no Linux?

Tags: linux, grep

Preciso utilizar o comando `tail -f`, para fazer uma busca em *logs* passados.
Sei que existem o `tail -f | grep ""`.

Porem não sei como buscar os antigos com parâmetro que desejo.
Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 1):

Para buscar arquivos que tenham determinada idade, pode-se usar o [`grep`](http://www.uniriotec.br/~morganna/guia/grep.html) em junção com o [`find`](http://www.uniriotec.br/~morganna/guia/find.html) através da opção `-mtime` para realizar a busca.

O exemplo abaixo vai procurar pela palavra *foo* em todos os arquivos modificados até 20 dias atrás no diretório atual.

```all
find . -type f -mtime -20 -print0 | xargs -0 grep -li 'foo'
```

Para buscar por arquivos modificados há *n* minutos atrás use `-mmin` ao invés de `-mtime`.

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se entendi bem a pergunta. Você precisa buscar algo em logs antigos?

Se for esse o caso, você não deve precisar do tail -f, ele só é útil para acompanhar logs que estão rodando nesse momento (por exemplo, voce precisa ver alguma exception durante a navegação no seu site).

Para arquivos antigos (que não são mais alterados), só o grep deve funcionar.

Indo no diretorio dos logs voce pode rodar

`grep -i 'oquevoceprocura' *`

(o -i é para não diferenciar maiusculas de minusculas)

Isso ira buscar essa string em todos os arquivos do diretorio atual.

Mais sobre o grep:

http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_04_02.html

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-use-grep-command-in-linux-unix/

Comment: Eu vi a questão do -i. e agradeço a ajuda. Eu estava entendendo errado! Muito obrigado!